# How to delete list of email addresses from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database-mail

I have a list of invalid email addresses parsed in the following format;

[image]

There are roughly 1500 invalid addresses, and I need to remove them from my myBB users.

What SQL query can I run to remove the list from my database?

Comment: What is the logic you use to decide between valid and invalid email addresses?

Comment: Not sure if I've understood your requirements exactly, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759596/validate-email-addresses-in-mysql) might be of interest - MySQL regexps for email.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a main table like this

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can built the table that contains the ids of the users with bad email addresses

```
CREATE TABLE users_invalid_emails
SELECT id.email FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'email%' and email LIKE '%@domain.com';
ALTER TABLE users_invalid_emails ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Look over the content of `users_invalid_emails`. If the emails in that table are to be deleted, you can now do a DELETE JOIN:

```
DELETE A.* FROM users A INNER JOIN users_invalid_emails B USING (id);
```

Before you do this, make sure you have a backup of the table.

In your case, the code will be

```
CREATE TABLE myBBusers_invalid_emails
SELECT id.email FROM my_BBusers WHERE email LIKE 'email%' and email LIKE '%@domain.com';
ALTER TABLE myBBusers_invalid_emails ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
DELETE A.* FROM my_BBusers A INNER JOIN myBBusers_invalid_emails B USING (id);
DROP TABLE myBBusers_invalid_emails;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: As I'm new to mySQL and direct edits, I'm not sure of your experience with myBB, but I'll give you an example of a the fields within myBB_users; http://puu.sh/7LAHG.png

How would I use your code to work with the myBB_users table?

Comment: @Rolando, What's the performance of `delete join`? Would it be as slow as `delete from x where email in (....)`?

Answer (score 0):

In case of you are having a list of the mail adresses maybe like that 'email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com' etc... you could do a simple

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE email in ('email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com');
```

This might not be the best solution, but the easiest to undersand IMHO ;) However, be careful as delete means delete in most cases as in data are gone. Also not how your application handles deleting users like that.